# How to prevent lazy loading of entities that were already manually loaded when navigating a property in EntityFramework

Tags: entity-framework-4, lazy-loading, objectcontext

**Background:**
I am using EF4 and `ObjectContext`. To optimze retrieval of complex object hierarchies, I manually execute database queries and then use `ObjectContext.Translatey<T>(DataReader, entitySetName, mergeOptions.AppendOnly)` to turn data rows into entities. I then attach the entities to the `ObjectContext` with `Attach` method. This also fixes relations between entities.

**The problem:**
After everything is loaded and set up I try to navigate from parent entity to a child entity (for example Parent.Childs.First()), but EF hits the database to load the kids, even though all the child entities are already present in the ObjectContext and EntitySet. It looks like the reason for this is that parent.Childs.IsLoaded is set to false which makes EF think that it still needs to load the relation.

**Question:**
How can I tell EF that EntitySet has already been loaded?

Is there a supported way to set `RelatedEnd.IsLoaded` to true. I wouldn't like to mess with the calling the `RelatedEnd.SetIsLoaded` internal method.

I found a smilar question [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/adonetefx/thread/c8d7733c-da9b-4f25-9648-0c64cda9a8b1) but it relates to DbContext and has no satifying answer  ;-)

Matra

Comment: I think you should dispose your context after the hierarchy has been loaded.

Comment: Gert, thanks, but I need the entities to be part of ObjectContext because I about to make changes to them and later want to call ObjectContext.SaveChanges. 

Btw: if I Translate the objects with MergeOption.NoTracaking the lazy loading does not occur (because the entity is not associated wiith the ObjectCOntext), but in this case I also loose tracking of changes.

Comment: But you will solve the lazy loading problem. You can save changes by temporarily attaching objects to a context. Contexts are supposed to have a short life span.

Comment: Gert, detaching and re-attaching all the entities to another context would also disable lazy loading for entities that are not yet part of the context (correct me if I am wrong). In my question I am asking how to "prevent lazy loading of entities/relations that have already been manually loaded". There are some of the entities/relations that will not be manually loaded and for them I want to preserve the lazy loading provided by ObjectContext.

Comment: You can also load objects by temporarily attaching the parent objects to a new context. This really is the way to go if you want to pre-load a hierarchy but not all adhering objects. The alternative is to keep the context alive and use lazy loading from the start (without pre-loading).

Comment: I don't think that temporary attaching parent object to a new context would work. MSDN doc. for RelatedEnd.IsLoaded states "When an object is detached, the IsLoaded flag is changed from false to true.".If this is true on re-attach there would be no lazy loading. I am keeping the ObjectContext alive and have lazyLoading=true. I want to do the preloading of some of the relations, since for the hierachical entities EF generates a lot of SQL statements and round trips to database (iamgine heirarchy 5 levels deep with 5 childs for each parent), but I can retrieve all these in single SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like this was implemented in this change:
http://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/269

You can now iterate through your entities and tell them that their child collections are already loaded:

```
foreach (var entity in loadedEntities)
  context.Entry(entity).Collection(a => a.SomeChildCollection).IsLoaded = true;
```

This will prevent entities in `SomeChildCollection` from being loaded when they are accessed from `entity`.

I'm not exactly sure what version of EF this appeared in but I'm guessing 6.0.0.

Comment: Yes, I have submitted that change request to codeplex, and its good to see, that it was implemented ;-)

Answer (score 0):

The only way to solve this is to turn off lazy loading. The question you have found on MSDN asks about `DbContext` but the answer mentions that there is no way to change the value in underlying libraries - ObjectContext API (= EF4 in your case) is the underlying library. Even in .NET 4.5 (EF5) setting `IsLoaded` is still not available on public API.

Comment: Ladislav, as explaind above I still need lazy loading for the rest of the entities that has not been loaded yet. It looks like that even beta version of EF6 does not support this yet, therefore, I've filled in a feature request http://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/884.